# How to add data from a List<List<String>> to a list view

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview

i'm having a `List<List<String>>` MyList and which contains

```
    { "A1","B1","C1" }
    { "A2","B2","C2" }
    { "A3","B3","C3" }
```

i need to add this to a ListView control with three columns

so the list view will be like

```
__Clm1________________Clm2________________Clm3_______________

   A1                  A2                 A2
   B1                  B2                 B3
   C1                  C2                 C3
```

Is there any way to do this using LINQ

**EDIT** Here is my solution for this :

```
ListViewItem[] lItem = MyList.Select(
                                          X => new ListViewItem(X.ToArray())
                                    ).ToArray();
listView1.Items.AddRange(lItem);
```

But here i need to add an Index.... The List view will be like

```
___S.No __Clm1________________Clm2________________Clm3_______________
   1      A1                  A2                 A2
   2      B1                  B2                 B3
   3      C1                  C2                 C3
```

How to add index to the listview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.. I got a solution.... Here it is

```
int i=1;
ListViewItem[] lItem =MyList.Select(X=> new ListViewItem(new String[]{i++.ToString()}.Concat(X).ToArray())).ToArray(); 
listView1.Items.AddRange(lItem);
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally I find this a lot cleaner:

```
var myList = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>(){ "A1","B1","C1" },
    new List<string>(){ "A2","B2","C2" },
    new List<string>(){ "A3","B3","C3" },
};

listView.BeginUpdate();    
foreach (var row in myList)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem(listView.Items.Count.ToString());
    item.SubItems.AddRange(row);
    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
listView.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you find you're working with `ListView` controls like this a lot, it may be worth it to add some simple extension methods:

```
public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    public static ListView AddItems(this ListView listView,
        IEnumerable<ListViewItem> items)
    {
        listView.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
        return listView;
    }

    public static ListViewItem WithSubItems(this ListViewItem item,
        IEnumerable<string> subItems)
    {
        item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems.ToArray());
        return item;
    }
}
```

The resulting code becomes very terse and clear:

```
var rows = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>(){ "A1","B1","C1" },
    new List<string>(){ "A2","B2","C2" },
    new List<string>(){ "A3","B3","C3" },
};

listView1.AddItems(
    rows.Select(
        (row, index) => new ListViewItem(index.ToString())
            .WithSubItems(row)
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the overload of `Select` that takes an index:

```
var rows = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>(){ "A1","B1","C1" },
    new List<string>(){ "A2","B2","C2" },
    new List<string>(){ "A3","B3","C3" },
};

listView1.Items.AddRange(
    rows.Select(
        (row, index) => new ListViewItem(
            new[] { index.ToString() }
                .Concat(row)
                .ToArray()
            )
        )
        .ToArray()
    );
```

I would personally use different styles to do this (local delegates, or extension methods + fluent syntax), since I don't really like calling ToArray inline, but this is as close to built-in as you're going to get :)

See my other answer if you're interested in the extension method + fluent syntax option.

Comment: Why not add each row to the listview directly instead of first building a new array?

Comment: @jgauffin: In the real scenario, the variable `blah` comes from thin air (another function).  It isn't actually available inline like my example here.  This example exists to show how to code the `AddRange` line.  Also, if you're talking about why I need `ToArray()`, this is because the `AddRange` method and `ListViewItem` constructors take arrays, not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @jgauffin: Of course, you could always use foreach loops ;)  His other question asked "how to do X in LINQ" (how to convert an `XDocument` into the `List<List<string>>` he has at the beginning of this question), so I figured he wanted in-line/declarative/"LINQ style" answers.

Comment: What I meant was that the `listView1.Items.AddRange` could be replaced with a `listView1.Items.Add` in the traversal of `blah`.